# Determine last row with data to compare two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to modify VBA code comparing two columns.

I found it at exceltip.com:

```
Sub PullUniques()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A40")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B40"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B40")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A40"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Since it handles 40 rows I've tried to edit to something like this:

```
Sub PullUniques()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("A2").End(xlDown)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2").End(xlDown), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range("B2").End(xlDown)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2").End(xlDown), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It gave me only one row that isn't matching for column. Probably I used "End(xlDown)" in a wrong way.

I created something like this, but it is slow (the file I will compare won't exceed 100k rows anyway):

```
Sub PullUniques()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A99999")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B99999"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B99999")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A99999"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to optimize it? Why does End(xlDown) fail?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code as follows:

```
Sub PullUniques()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Range("B2"),Range("B2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range(Range("B2"),Range("B2").End(xlDown))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`.End(xlDown)` only refers to one cell.

Answer (score 0):

This was more of an exercise to see if I can come up with an implementation a bit more efficient

Here are the test results

```
Compare2Cols() - Rows:    10,001; Time:   0.047 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -   4.277 sec
Compare2Cols() - Rows:    20,001; Time:   0.109 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -  15.975 sec
Compare2Cols() - Rows:    30,001; Time:   0.156 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -  31.982 sec
Compare2Cols() - Rows:    40,001; Time:   0.234 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -  64.472 sec
Compare2Cols() - Rows:    50,001; Time:   0.296 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() - 104.645 sec
Compare2Cols() - Rows:   100,001; Time:   1.232 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -     N/A
Compare2Cols() - Rows:   500,001; Time:  31.934 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -     N/A
Compare2Cols() - Rows: 1,048,576; Time: 126.797 sec;     PullUniquesFixed() -     N/A
```

---

.

> **PullUniquesFixed()**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PullUniquesFixed()
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim rngCell As Range, t As Double, tr As String
    t = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws.UsedRange
        For Each rngCell In .Columns(1).Offset(1).Cells
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(2), rngCell) = 0 Then
                Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
            End If
        Next
        For Each rngCell In .Columns(2).Offset(1).Cells
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(1), rngCell) = 0 Then
                Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    tr = "PullUniques()        - Rows: " & Format(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "#,###") & "; "
    Debug.Print tr & "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

A note related to `End(xlDown)` - it may not work as you want if you have empty cells in your column. For example, in my test image in column B, `Range("B2").End(xlDown)` will return row 4 (the same as if you click B2 and press Down Arrow) so it will ignore all cells bellow, so sometimes it might work better if you use `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` - same as selecting the last cell in the column (1M rows +) and pressing Up arrow

---

.

> **Compare2Cols()** - It uses 2 dictionaries and 4 arrays for better performance

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Compare2Cols()
    Dim dColA As Object:    Set dColA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dColB As Object:    Set dColB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ur As Range:        Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete
    Dim arrA As Variant:    arrA = ur.Columns("A")
    Dim arrB As Variant:    arrB = ur.Columns("B")
    Dim arrC As Variant:    arrC = ur.Columns("C")
    Dim arrD As Variant:    arrD = ur.Columns("D")

    Dim itm As Variant, r As Long
    For Each itm In arrA
        dColA(itm) = 0
    Next
    For Each itm In arrB
        dColB(itm) = 0
    Next

    For Each itm In dColA
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColB.Exists(itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next
    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColB
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColA.Exists(itm) Then arrD(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 2 in 1
    Next

    ur.Columns("C") = arrC
    ur.Columns("D") = arrD
End Sub
```

---

Test data

[image: TestData]